# Browser Fails to Render Qweb

Tags: javascript, odoo-8, qweb, kanban

I'm designing a Kanban view for my task application. But when I add the following lines of code to render mail followers (or Partner) ID's, I get an odoo client error ([Click here](https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipMvsawEnKfTn2p3s0so2WUuZM9kWTxwi5PYePU5teBTbNHXQOG-MunjqioEWXBxqg?key=T1czQWE2WHBDNll6NGNQM1ZyNDg4bnZRZWxUSWJn))

```
<t t-foreach="record.message_follower_ids.value" t-as="rec">
   <t t-esc="rec" />;
</t>
```

Here is the full kanban definition:

```
<templates>


<t t-name="kanban-box">
  <div class="oe_kanban_card">
<div class="oe_kanban_content">  
  <h4>
        <a type="open">
      <field name="name" />
    </a>
  </h4>
      <field name="tag_ids" />
  <ul>
    <li><field name="user_id" /></li>
    <li><field name="date_deadline" /></li>
    <t t-if="record.effort_estimate.raw_value > 0">
      <li>Estimate <field name="effort_estimate"/></li>
        </t>
      </ul>
      <div class="oe_kanban_bottom_right">
        <field name="kanban_state"
         widget="kanban_state_selection"/>
      </div>
      <div class="oe_kanban_footer_left">
        <field name="priority" widget="priority"/>                                      
      </div>
      <t t-foreach="record.message_follower_ids.value" t-as="rec">
        <t t-esc="rec" />;
      </t>
    </div>
  </div>
</t>                        
</templates>
```

Answer (score 0):

For fields to be used in qweb templates they needed to be declared in the body of the kanban tag before they are used in the template tag.

```
<kanban>
<field name="message_follower_ids"/>    
<templates>
    <t t-name="kanban-box">
        <div class="oe_kanban_card">
            <div class="oe_kanban_content">  
                <h4>
                    <a type="open">
                        <field name="name" />
                    </a>
                </h4>
                <field name="tag_ids" />
                <ul>
                    <li><field name="user_id" /></li>
                    <li><field name="date_deadline" /></li>
                    <t t-if="record.effort_estimate.raw_value > 0">
                        <li>Estimate <field name="effort_estimate"/></li>
                    </t>
                </ul>
                <div class="oe_kanban_bottom_right">
                    <field name="kanban_state"
                        widget="kanban_state_selection"/>
                </div>
                <div class="oe_kanban_footer_left">
                    <field name="priority" widget="priority"/>                                      
                </div>
                <t t-foreach="record.message_follower_ids.value" t-as="rec">
                    <t t-esc="rec" />;
                </t>
            </div>
        </div>
    </t>                        
</templates>
```